# Vpc.FromLookup keeps returning vpc-12345

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

When I try to lookup a vpc by name in my cdk codepipeline I keep getting vpc-12345 which doesnt exist:

```
var vpc = Vpc.FromLookup(this, canamVpc, new VpcLookupOptions()
        {
            VpcName = "MyVPC"

        });
```

any idea how to find a vpc based on a name or tag? I don't want to hard code the vpc id in an from attributes search, id's change , names don't.

Comment: There is no such vpc with an id vpc-12345 in any of our regions/accounts, whats more this "dummy" vpc coming back seems to have cidr of 1.2.3.4/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**  Synth your app locally one time to populate the context cache.  Commit the result.

---

`FromLookup` is a CDK [context method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html#context_methods).  Context methods make one cloud-side call and cache the results in `cdk.context.json`.  Subsequent calls read from the cache.

The CDK initializes the cache with dummy data like `vpc-12345`. You are seeing the placeholder data because `FromLookup` hasn't yet made the initial cloud-side call to get your real VPC info into the cache.  This is because your CDK pipeline doesn't have permissions required for the API call.

There's a whole section about [Context Lookups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#context-lookups) in the CDK pipeline docs.  The recommended solution is simple:

> Our recommended way of using lookups is by running cdk synth on the developer workstation and checking in the `cdk.context.json` file, which contains the results of the context lookups. This will make sure your synthesized infrastructure is consistent and repeatable.

"Deterministic deploys" that avoid the possible side-effects of "live", uncontrolled API calls is a CDK [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-context).

Comment: It is worth noting that when a stack contains lookup method whose value isn't yet saved in `cdk.context.json`, `cdk synth` will synth the stack twice - the first time the lookup methods return dummy values, then the lookup is resolved, and then a second time right after that with the real values. So you don't "have to" commit the result (even though it's best practice) - it will just return the actual value on the second synth.

Comment: thanks, this is what I figured out, I was going to ask so what happens when a private subnet is recreated and no longer has that id? and it seems the answer is it should break and you decide whether to repull and cache the VPC info again. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @user2612665 Glad to help.  Yes, exactly: if the VPC config changes, synth and commit again.